# C++ GlutCloseFunc coming Up with Init error

Tags: c++, freeglut

I am trying to specify the glutClosefunc for the tutorial at
http://www.glprogramming.com/red/index.html
but it doesnt seem to work...

my code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutCloseFunc(close);  //This isnt working
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Its currently coming up with
freeglut ERROR: function  called without first calling 'glutInit'

The code example was a C example... i converted the parameters in main to C++, but i didnt change glutInit...

oh yeah, you can see i am using freeglut instead of glut like the tutorial says as well

Comment: Are you sure that glutCloseFunc is what's causing the error message, and not glutMainLoop? It seems odd that you'd call the close function before the main loop function.

Comment: no I have now realised that not only does glutCloseFunc does the error, but whenever i use glutLeaveMainLoop, i get the same error and commenting out the glutInit() call dosent change the situation... the game still runs, and it still comes up with the same error... i think my freeglut might be a dud... i will check that...

Comment: ok updated freeglut.. still a no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I figured it out.. I had, in my linker input, linked to `glut32.lib` instead of `freeglut.lib` and therefore freeglut wasnt initializing properly!